# Community for Excel questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which community should I join for asking questions similar to following? I don't feel SO would be appropriate as I'm looking to be using GUI, and not writing code to do so.

---

**Sample question:**

I have a table in Excel like this:

[image: sample table]

And I want to convert it to a normal table using the Excel GUI, my desired result is:

```
F11 F12 F13 R11 R12 R13 10

F11 F12 F13 R21 R22 R23 20

F21 F22 F23 R11 R12 R13 30

F21 F22 F23 R21 R22 R23 40
```

Comment: Is it a VBA related question?

Comment: Depends on the question. This ^ question is just too broad to be able to answer sanely.

Comment: Thanks for your comments ... my question is about converting pivot tables to normal tables

Comment: How? Manually by using the excel GUI? Programmatically? You want to outsource it?

Comment: BTW, you can always ask at the official MS Office forums http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office (Because I'm niot sure there's a SE site for this type of questions)

Comment: I want to do that using GUI... which community is suitable to ask this type of questions?

Comment: If you want us to tell you where to ask a question, you have to tell us what the question actually is, not some vague hand-wavy description of what the question might be when you eventually decide to sit down and write it. There is no community suitable for low-quality questions.

Comment: The answer to your question is probably: copy & paste

Comment: @CodyGray I edited my question ... I just wanted to know the proper community and ask my question in detail there ... BTW thanks for your comment

Comment: Is [spreadsheet programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet#Spreadsheet_programs) programming?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question about Excel *may* be on-topic for [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel). From their [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about ...
>
> ...
>
> - computer software

Make sure that your question is reasonably scoped and otherwise meet their [question criteria](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask), though.